# django models.ForeignKey("Tablename) or models.Foreignkey(Tablenamevariable)

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, foreign-keys

Im looking at the django-generated model classes using inspectdb.

I noticed that sometimes strings and sometimes variable names are called based on their "read from top to bottom" appearance in the file.

here and example

```
class AuthGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=150)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'auth_group'


class AuthGroupPermissions(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey(AuthGroup, models.DO_NOTHING)
    permission = models.ForeignKey('AuthPermission', models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'auth_group_permissions'
        unique_together = (('group', 'permission'),)


class AuthPermission(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey('DjangoContentType', models.DO_NOTHING)
    codename = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'auth_permission'
        unique_together = (('content_type', 'codename'),)
```

Using a legacy db (mysql) in my case.

Quesion is:
Can i not just always use the string name of the table insead of sometimes string sometimes variable? That would be safer in my case
Would these two statements not do the same thing?

```
group = models.ForeignKey('AuthGroup', models.DO_NOTHING)
permission = models.ForeignKey('AuthPermission', models.DO_NOTHING)
```

Comment: Looking at your code, it seems that both of the syntaxes are functionally equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

> Quesion is: Can i not just always use the string name of the table insead of sometimes string sometimes variable?

**Yes**: using `ForeignKey(Foo, …)` can be replaced with `ForeignKey('Foo', …)`. A string literal is often used to refer to a model that will be defined further in the file, since you can not use `Foo` if the `Foo` class is not yet defined.

But if you want, you can use string literals for all the `ForeignKey`s. You can refer to a model with `'app_name.ModelName'` or with simply `'ModelName'` if the model is defined for the same app name as the model you are defining.

Comment: thanks a lot! took a lot of worries off my shoulders there!